# cloud sql mysql go away if no root user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

There is a update query with 3 sub select .

If run it in root it will success, But in other user(not root permission) it goes away.

The code (php laravel)

```php
$sql ='............ update someting with left join used';
$params = [$id];
$result = DB::update($sql, $params);
```

Comment: you mean you only can use root to execute your php code to execute sql?

Comment: no, Root can run sucess ,But no root user will fail(If **not set database name in query**);I have no ideal the code runs well if using mysql5.7 in local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solutin **add database name to query** .It solved my problem but I have no idea why?

ps: I am using php and laravel's db update;